# How to optimize a frequently read method in a python class?

Tags: python

There are many methods defined in `MyClass` that needs to call `read_my_obj`, is the code below a good way to avoid re-creating a new MyObjectType instance every time to save memory and improve execution speed? Or is there a more pythonic way to do achieve this type of pattern?

```py
class MyClass:
  my_obj: Optional[MyObjectType] = None
  
  @classmethod
  def read_my_obj(cls) -> MyObjectType:
     if cls.my_obj is not None:
         return cls.my_obj  # treating my_obj as a singleton, to avoid instantiating a new one each time
     obj_field = read_from_db()
     cls.my_obj = MyObjectType(obj_field)  # instantiate my object for first time
     return cls.my_obj
```

Comment: I think that the question, as it is formulated now, tends to attract opinion-based answers. Maybe you could make it into a objective question instead of subjective, or it could be submitted in the Code Review Stack exchange site.

Comment: You can consider using [functools.cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache)

Comment: Functools cache is a purely functional approach and doesn't address the question of storing said value as an attribute. (A necessity when interacting with DB objects.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [hidden attribute + property](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#member-objects-and-slots) to achieve "run-time" caching of instantiated objects:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._my_obj = None  # hidden attribute begins with an underscore
 
    @property
    def my_obj(self): -> MyObjectType
        # Create if not exists
        if not self._my_obj:
            obj_field = read_from_db()
            self._my_obj = MyObjectType(obj_field)
        # return hidden attribute
        return self._my_obj
```

Do note that this hidden attribute will only get populated once per class instance (on accessing property). If you need more frequent refreshes, you could configure some datetime logic within the property.